# Personal deductions when filing taxes in the US

Tags: data-request, usa, taxes

I am looking for a data set listing the amount of [personal deductions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tax_deduction#Personal_deductions) from the [federal tax income](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxation_in_the_United_States#Income_tax) as collected by the Internal Revenue Service (IRS) in the United States, broken down in deduction categories (such as medical expenses or giving to charity).

By amount of personal deductions, I mean the total amount as summed over all taxpayers in the United States.

E.g.:

- In 2015, 1.2 billion USD were deducted as medical expenses.
- In 2015, 30 million USD were deducted as [lifetime learning](https://turbotax.intuit.com/tax-tools/tax-tips/Tax-Deductions-and-Credits/9-Things-You-Didn-t-Know-Were-Tax-Deductions/INF26934.html).

Ideally, I would like to have a historical overview. (i.e., the evolution of these numbers over the years)

Comment: https://www.irs.gov/uac/Tax-Stats-2